# How to switch between 2 stream inputs after a set duration using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspberry-pi4

I am tinkering with my two Raspberry Pis and would like to do the following:

Both Pis record via a camera and stream it via cvlc to the network. Then one of them uses both streams to make a single stream which alternates between both sources every 30 seconds.
My setup is as below:

Pi 3 (192.168.0.158) and Pi 4 (192.168.0.87) both use the following command to stream the camera feed to my local network:

```
raspivid -o - -t 0 -vf -hf -fps 30 -b 6000000 | cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=:8090}' :demux=h264
```

The Pi 4 then uses

```
ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls,crypto -f concat -safe 0 -i stream_list.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

with content of stream_list.txt being:

```
file http:\/\/192.168.0.87:8090
duration 00:00:02.00
file http:\/\/192.168.0.158:8090
duration 00:00:02.00
```

I use output.mp4 as test, this will be a twitch server or somewhat. The current duration is 2 seconds just for testing as well. And I will add a loop -1 to keep switching. My problem is that the process doesn't stop after 4 seconds. It keeps "recording" forever until I CTRL+C and then output.mp4 only contains the camera feed of the first mentioned stream in the stream_list.txt. It doesn't stop after 2 seconds switches to the other stream and then stops after another 2 seconds as I expected.

Is there something that I am essentially doing wrong or am I at least somewhat on the right way?